# Postfix: hostname being stripped due to subdomain

Tags: postfix, redhat

How do you prevent Postfix 2.6.6-2.2 from stripping the hostname off of a server that uses subdomains?

```
FQDN: hostname.dev.example.com
```

Here is what the delivered message contains:

```
From: <root@dev.example.com>
```

I've played around with `myhostname`, `mydomain`, `myorigin` settings, but the hostname is always stripped off and it will only recognize three positions of the FQDN.

```
main.cf:  #myhostname
          #mydomain
results:  From:<root@hostname.localdomain>


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname.dev.example.com
results:  From:<root@dev.example.com>


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname
          mydomain = dev.example.com
results:  From:<root@dev.example.com>


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname.dev
          mydomain = example.com
results:  From:<root@dev.example.com>


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname\.dev.example.com
results:  Postfix error


main.cf:  myhostname = "hostname.dev.example.com"
results:  Postfix error


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname.dev.example
results:  From:<root@hostname.dev.example>


main.cf:  mydomain = dev.example.com
results:  From:<root@dev.example.com>


main.cf:  myhostname = hostname.dev
          myorigin = example.com
results:  From:<root@example.com>


main.cf:  myorigin = hostname.dev.example.com
results:  From:<root@dev.example.com>
```

---

Here's the goal:

```
From: <root@hostname.dev.example.com>
```

Comment: It appears as those our Exchange server was stripping off the hostname and Postfix wasn't to blame.  Thanks for the help NickW.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with [smtp_generic_maps](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic), basically it's a text file with the from you want to change, and the from you want to change it to:

> /etc/postfix/generic

```
root@hostname.localdomain      root@hostname.dev.example.com
```

then add it into main.cf like this:

> smtp_generic_maps hash:/etc/postfix/generic

run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` and restart postfix to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but that's giving me the same results of <root@dev.example.com>.

Comment: Is that for local delivery, or to another server?

Comment: Plus obviously the address on the left hand side needs to be exactly what you see it as, not what I offered as an example.

Comment: Yes, I understood that I needed to customize it for my environment and it exactly matches the incorrect From address.  The message is being delivered to an Exchange relay host.  No matter what combination I use, it will only recognize three positions in the domain name.

Comment: I can't find anything specific about the number of subdomains that are "valid" in an email address, this might be something that you want to ask on the postfix list..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2014 question... but here in 2018 it's the first result in Google.

The answer I found to work is to set the masquerade_domains option to exactly what you want the mailserver to tell another mailserver ... e.g.

```
masquerade_domains = example.com
```